# Error Message: redirect_uri URL is not properly formatted error

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The following error started popping up in my applications about 2 hours ago.

All three applications are hosted on the same server using shared SSL.

> An error occurred with `<application name>`. Please try again later.
>
> API Error Code: 100 API Error Description: Invalid parameter Error
>   Message: redirect_uri URL is not properly formatted

Any ideas on what would cause this sudden change in my apps?

The error pops up when I try to use the function `sendRequestToManyRecipients()` or when posting to a users wall.

Code used to generate the popup

```
<script>
    FB.init({
        appId  : '<?php echo $fbconfig['appid']?>',
        status : true,
        cookie : true,
        oauth: false
    });

    function sendRequestToManyRecipients() {
        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: ('I just entered the Payntwagon Audo Targa Terminator Competition! Payntwagon Audio is giving away a brand new Targa Terminator 4 channel amplifier! Enter today to win!'), href: 'http://www.facebook.com/payntwagon?sk=app_279329708764904',
        }, requestCallback);
    }


    function requestCallback(response)
    {
        if(response && response.request) {
            loadPopup();
        } else {

        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do the following :

1) encode the url before sending, ie both fb url as well as return url
   u can use javascript functions or php functions for encoding url

//encodeURIComponent(url); // in javascript u can do this

2) Also check that the return url specified is valid
```

Comment: Im lost here. Not sure exactly which URLs need to be encoded and also where do I check to return URL?

Comment: Yeah the url is encoded to skip special characters , the return url should be url encoded , and if the whole url contain any special character that too u can encode

Comment: I take it the URL that needs to be encoded would be the Canvas URL? I can't find any place to encode it or the return URL. 

Any suggestions?

Comment: can u please share the url/code here , so that i can suggest u details clearly

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The URL to the app is https://secure780.websitewelcome.com/~untitle2/payntwagon/facebook/ and the app sits inside Facebook at https://www.facebook.com/payntwagon?sk=app_279329708764904

The code to generate the popup to invite I will post in the original question.

Comment: While using facebook applications , first we need to authenticate our session with facebook using the secret key and id that we get while creating a fb app, after that e need to get a session key to access our app and after getting that we proceed with comamnds to facebook to do things, so while getting a session key , we need to pass a return url to facebook , the fb will automatically send the session key to that url after authenticating our app, so if this is the context , please go though fb app details, also u can post ur need..

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is making no sense to me. Applications worked 100% until 3 hours ago when the post to wall and share with friends features stopped working on all three applications.

Comment: This just started happening in my application... was working perfectly fine for months and I went on to check and none of the comment boxes are showing up it just says "href URL is not properly formatted" did you ever find a solution to this issue?